# Missing line breaks in multiline text field when placed in Page Layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout, multiline-text-field

I have created page content type in which there is one field of type `Multiple lines of text` where I am storing comments of Page.

I have created page layout and displaying the comments on page. But the line breaks are not render in the page layout in display mode.

The page layout contains following code.

`<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Comments" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue>`

Below is the image of the item's display form where it looks fine with line breaks.

[image]

Below is the image of the page layout where the multi line text box field displays value in the straight line.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer really late but it wasted hours of mine to find the correct approach while it was really a very small thing to be changed. So, to save other's time :

```
<SharePointWebControls:RichTextField FieldName="Comments" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:RichTextField>
```

Instead of

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Comments" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue>
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because in your page layout you are specifying a text field (SharePointWebControls:FieldValue) where you really want to display using a HTML field. try using the following instead.

```
    <PageFieldNoteField:NoteField FieldName="68f3c200-fee2-413d-9be2-2b23817ad133" runat="server">
```

Note field seems strange but its the right one to use as long as your **comments** field is set to be HTML.

Comment: Did this work? Worthwhile feeding this back...

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is that, Multiline puts uses `Environment.NewLine` and which in returns gives `\n`, this is not rendered correctly in html, and thus result in straight text in display mode.

You will need to replace this new line with "`<br/>`", then it should work fine.